# Beginner's question about homotopy type in Milnor's Morse Theory

Tags: morse-theory

In the introductory section of Milnor's *Morse Theory*, he gives an example of the torus.

[image: Diagram 1 from Morse Theory by John Milnor]

The set of points of the torus which have height less than $a$ for some $p<a<q$ is just a solid disk, i.e., a 2-cell. When we move from $q$ to $r$, we start getting a cylinder. Milnor notes that moving from a 2-cell to a cylinder is the same (homotopically) as attaching a 1-cell:

[image: Image from Morse Theory by John Milnor]

I can sort of understand why: A cylinder can be squashed into a circle, and the bottom half of the left side is homotopically a point, so both sides are homotopically the same as a circle.

But at the same time, moving from $q$ to $r$ means attaching something which looks kind of like the pair of pants:

[image]

We can squash the legs together to get a circle, so doesn't this mean that we are attaching a circle to our disk, instead of just a line?

Comment: Do you start with a torus (and not a solid torus)?

Comment: @posilon Yes, should just be $S^1\times S^1$, I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of pants doesn't have the same homotopy type as a circle. You can flatten it and then contract it to the shape of the digit `8`, i.e. two circles glued at a point.
[image: pair of pants contracting to figure 8]
In any case, who says that the cancellation law holds when gluing topological spaces together? You know that
$$\text{disk} + \text{pair of pants} \approx \text{disk} + \text{line.}$$
Why should you expect that
$$\text{pair of pants} \approx \text{line?}$$