# Morse theory graphic

Tags: graphing-functions, morse-theory

How can I make the images that appear in Morse theory?. Type [Beginner's question about homotopy type in Milnor's Morse Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980682/beginners-question-about-homotopy-type-in-milnors-morse-theory), i try in geogebra but i cannot.

Comment: Some mathematicians I know use vector graphics software--- which is probably your best bet for flexibility in design and scalability in quality.

Comment: In the reference you give, the figures are very different : which one especialy would you like to reproduce ?

Comment: Ask Patrick Clément who is able to do many [nice surfaces](https://www.geogebra.org/u/patrick+cl%C3%A9ment) with GeoGebra

Comment: I would like to reproduce the image of the torus and the line of real numbers where the critical points are.

Comment: Have a look at the excellent videos by Tim Brzezinski : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgzeGa2bYys , 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2nBmryWoj8 , etc...